# How to make an International Soundex?

Tags: soundex

E.g. the Soundex algorithm is optimized for English.  Is there a more universal algorithm that would apply across large families of languages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SOUNDEX is indeed English-oriented.  Two others that take a wider variety of phonetic differences into account are: [Double Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Metaphone) and [NYSIIS](http://search.cpan.org/~krburton/String-Nysiis-1.00/Nysiis.pm).

They produce encodings into a much larger possible space than SOUNDEX does.  Double Metaphone, specifically, includes reductions with the express purpose of handling alternate pronunciations based on more languages than English.

I did a presentation on fuzzy string matching recently, [the slides](https://github.com/kyleburton/fuzzy-string/blob/master/fuzzy-matching.pdf?raw=true) may be helpful.

Comment: The link to your slides is broken (404)

Comment: @John: new link seems to be http://asymmetrical-view.com/talks/#fuzzy-string-matching

Comment: Thanks, I just updated it to point to the PDF in the related github repo - I hope that stays more constant.  Thanks.

Comment: On Slide 38, you're showing percentage similarities that are above %50 - I'm not saying it's wrong, but what formula are you using to calculate the similarity percentage from the edit distance?  The formula I've seen `1 / (1 + dist)` maxes out at 50% for inexact matches.  I know your costs are variable, but `1 / 1.4 != %93` which is the number you show in your slide.  Thanks!

Comment: I may not have the version you do - for me slide 38 is an edit distance grid :(  Which words are being compared that you're looking at?  The distance formula I usually use is (max(len(a),len(b)) - num_edits) / max(len(a),len(b)).  If you're looking at the Text Brew algorithm, it allows different costs for the various edits, I'm pretty sure I used the same formula - there is sample code in the github repo...if you can tell me what's on the slide in question I can probably better answer your question...or email me and we'll figure it out.